# How to pass in a list of ids into cosmos query using LINQ?

Tags: linq, azure-cosmosdb

We use cosmos LINQ queries to fetch data from cosmos.
But I have a requirement where I need to pass in list of ids and it needs to fetch all items which have that list.
For some reason, this code used to work, but now it fetches only the first item from that list

```
public Task<FeedResponse<Model>> Get(ConfigModel config, List<string> feedIds, Guid feedId, string name, int limit, string continuationToken)
        {
            Expression<Func<Model, bool>> queryFunc =
                m => 
                feedIds.Contains(m.FeedId.ToString());

            return GetByQuery(queryFunc, config, limit, continuationToken);
        }
```

The above query gets passed down to the cosmos Linq sql function and works as expected. My question is whats the right format to fetch items from cosmos based on a list of ids in LINQ

Answer (score 0):

> right format to fetch items from cosmos based on a list of Id's in LINQ.

**Below Is the format I followed to fetch items from cosmos based on a list of Id's in LINQ:**

- The **Id** values you want to filter by are defined in a `List<string>` called **IdList**.
- Using the Cosmos DB **endpoint URI** and **primary key** provided, create an instance of the `CosmosClient` class.
- Create a LINQ query to filter documents in the Cosmos DB container based on the **Id** field.
- To filter documents, use the Where clause to specify any value from the `IdList` that the **Id** attribute matches.
- Utilize the `ToFeedIterator()` function to create an iterator for the LINQ query. It will allow to retrieve the query results in pages.
- Execute the query asynchronously using a while loop that checks if there are more results. Use `ReadNextAsync` inside the loop to get the following page of results.

**Code I tried with:**

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string cosmosEndpointUri = "*****";
    string cosmosPrimaryKey = "*****";
    string databaseName = "idListDb";
    string containerName = "testCont";
    
    List<string> idList = new List<string> {"1", "3"};

    CosmosClient cosmosClient = new CosmosClient(cosmosEndpointUri, cosmosPrimaryKey);

    var database = cosmosClient.GetDatabase(databaseName);

    var container = database.GetContainer(containerName);

    var query = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<YourDocumentType>()
        .Where(d => idList.Contains(d.id));
    
    var iterator = query.ToFeedIterator<YourDocumentType>();

    while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        var response = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();

        foreach (var document in response)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Id: {document.id}, FirstName: {document.FirstName}, LastName: {document.LastName}, Email: {document.Email}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```js
Id: 1, FirstName: John, LastName: Doe, Email: johndoe@example.com
Id: 3, FirstName: Alice, LastName: Johnson, Email: alicejohnson@example.com
```